# I'm having problems making a Powershell Linq "Join" work [Explicit Argument Typing?]

Tags: linq, powershell, active-directory

I've been working on provisioning scripts between Oracle and Active Directory, and more specifically using Powershell scripts.  I found an excellent resource on using Linq in Powershell ([High Performance Powershell](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/high-performance-powershell-linq/#post-71022-_Toc482783695) by Michael Sorens) but I'm having trouble with the JOIN method, and I think it maybe be related to how I'm trying to type my arguments.  I have to admit I haven't fully grasped the example on the page ([Cross-Join](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/high-performance-powershell-linq/#post-71022-_Toc482783732)).  I'll set up the problem and then show what I'm trying (that has failed so far).

I have a database query that returns users who should be in Active Directory, and I have a "Get-ADUser" command that gets every person who IS in Active Directory.  I previously got the "Except" operator to work by reducing the number of properties in both to the ID (samaccountname).  So, at that point I could derive everyone who needed to be added, as well as everyone who needed to be removed.  But I was now reduced to a list of IDs (i.e. no longer had the full compliment of fields I would need... either to add the AD record OR to send a "you're about to be removed" email).

So, seeing the Join operator, I thought I'd re-join the remove list to the "get all users" AD result-set.  But... I keep getting the error

```
Cannot find an overload for "Join" and the argument count: "5"
```

The following was an attempt to simplify the moving parts, so it's two AD query results rather than the original problem (shows same error though).

```
$ad_host="my.adserver.edu"

$left = Get-ADUser -Server $ad_host -Identity 'knownuser' -Properties sAMAccountName | select sAMAccountName
$right = Get-ADUser -Server $ad_host -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=KnownUsersOU,OU=Students,OU=Users-Students,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=edu" -Properties sAMAccountName, givenName, sn | select sAMAccountName, givenName, sn

$outerKeyDelegate = [Func[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount,string]] { $args[0].sAMAccountName }
$innerKeyDelegate = [Func[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount,string]] { $args[0].sAMAccountName }
#$resultDelegate = [Func[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount,string,string]] {'{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}' -f $args[0].sAMAccountName, $args[1].givenName, $args[1].sn, $args[1].mail, $args[1].employeeID }
$resultDelegate = [Func[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount,string,string]] {'{0}, {1}' -f $args[0].sAMAccountName, $args[1].sAMAccountName }

[Linq.Enumerable]::Join($toRemove, $allUsers, $outerKeyDelegate, $innerKeyDelegate, $resultDelegate) | foreach { Add-Content -Path to_delete.csv -Value $_ }
```

So, in this case, I'm trying to explicitly type my join properties as Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount objects... I actually originally was using "string" since, the actual join property was the samaccountname, and when I ran a "getType()" on that, it returned "String"... well, actually it was "Name: String, BaseType: System.Object".

At this point, what I know is outweighed by what I don't know :)  I could do this EASILY by moving it all into a database to make the "list", but this seems like it'd be a lot more elegant if I could master Powershell-Linq!

Comment: Maybe this helps: [RamblingCookieMonster](http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Join-Object/) placed a [`Join-Object cmdlet`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join-Object/0.1.6) on the PowerShell gallery and his [project site](https://github.com/ili101/Join-Object) which uses `Linq`. (I also placed a [Join-Object](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join/2.2.2/DisplayScript) version on the PowerShell gallery and [my Project Site](https://github.com/iRon7/Join-Object) but doesn't using `Linq` and therefore slower but more strait forward and easier to use for e.g. a cross-join)

Comment: That's an excellent resource that I'll definitely be using... but I'm actually getting the same error, but now it's coming from that Module!  Well, at least that localizes what I'm misunderstanding.  Thanks for the link! Edit:  On further reading from his website, he uses something very close to exactly my use-case... and yet shows that to work.  That's interesting to say the least.

Comment: Ok, I suspect that error just means "something went wrong".  It was actually a miskey on my "-Left" object definition.  I passed "object.property" instead of just "object".  When I fixed that, it worked immediately!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is with types. Consider this command:

`$left = Get-ADUser -Server $ad_host -Identity 'knownuser' -Properties sAMAccountName | select sAMAccountName`

The type of this object will be `ADUser`.

And for this command:

`$right = Get-ADUser -Server $ad_host -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=KnownUsersOU,OU=Students,OU=Users-Students,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=edu" -Properties sAMAccountName, givenName, sn | select sAMAccountName, givenName, sn`

The type of the object will be `Object[]`. It needs to be `ADUser[]`.

You should be able to cast it like this:

`$right = [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser[]](Get-ADUser -Server $ad_host -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=KnownUsersOU,OU=Students,OU=Users-Students,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=edu" -Properties sAMAccountName, givenName, sn)`

Then, since you're dealing with `ADUser` objects, your key delegates must also match:

`$outerKeyDelegate = [Func[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser,string]] { $args[0].sAMAccountName }
$innerKeyDelegate = [Func[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser,string]] { $args[0].sAMAccountName }`

and your result delegate must also match to the type of objects you're working on (you were closer in your commented out code):

`$resultDelegate = [Func[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser,string]] {'{0}, {1}' -f $args[0].sAMAccountName, $args[1].sAMAccountName }`

Comment: I could never make this work, although I agree this is the area where the breakage is occurring.  I ended up using the Join-Object cmdlet mentioned in a comment above, but I would like to (eventually) figure this out at the lower level.